# SXA search result returns Error 400

Tags: sxa, content-search

I am using Sitecore 9.0.2 and SXA 1.7.1.
Search results return Error 400 with response "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." while facets return results as expected. any idea what might cause this issue??
[image]

Comment: Anything in the logs? Or more information when you execute that search call separately?

Comment: Nothing is thrown in the logs and when i execute it separately it throws "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: Have you added SXA specific SOLR cores into SOLR? Have you populated them and rebuild index? See chapters 3c, 3d and 3e of my blog post https://tothecore.sk/2019/07/22/sitecore-sxa-1-9-installation-guide-for-development-machine